# why two explorer windows are opened from visual studio in Azure project when I press F5

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

When I Press F5 to run the Azure project containing two worker roles and a web role. It opens two windows with same URL and they take so much time to open as well.

By time consuming, I mean, the website is taking too much time to load, but no such functionality or code is to be executed in the controller.

Can any body guide me on this?

Comment: Just curious - which browser(s) were you seeing this happen with? As stated in my answer, I've seen this happen in Chrome and Firefox, but not with IE9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this happen before as well.

However, there is a way around it. You can edit the ServiceConfiguration.cscfg for your web role and set the instance count to 0. Then set your actual web application as the startup project instead of the Azure Web Role. This will allow you to use Cassini / IIS Express instead of the Compute Emulator to develop your web application.

NOTE: When you do a deployment you will have to set the instance count to something greater than one.

```
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="Web" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration" osFamily="2" osVersion="*">
  <Role name="WebRole1">
    <Instances count="0" />
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="LogLevel" value="Error" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
  </Role>
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

ALSO NOTE: There are certain features you will not be able to test when running your site like this. One example is local storage. If you're using features like that in your application you can simply switch the configuration and startup project back.

You'll also notice a huge speed increase when you press F5 to debug your application.

Comment: Your work around worked for opening one browser window. This looks like a bug in the Azure account. There was not much boost in the speed of the website. The issue is present locally not on the cloud, but thanks for your answer, because it gave a solution for the question I asked...

Answer (score 1):

It takes more time to start Azure project simply because it does more stuff. Just for starters, every time you press F5, it creates and configures new application pool for each role, then it creates and configures new web sites for each role instance.

I found it sometimes much faster to start the sites by pressing Ctrl+F5 (i.e. start without debugging). Then you can attach to your process manually, but you are free to do modifications to many files without re-deploying roles. This is especially helpful if you modify something that does not require rebuilding your binaries.

For your other question, you can control how browsers are launched for HTTP and HTTPS endpoints by using Configuration tab of the role properties. Just uncheck endpoints you don't want your browser to be launched on.

Comment: Thanks for the information regarding configuration tab on role properties. When I said the website is running slowly I meant that it took too much time after the browser has launched and the initial display of the website. Although it is not doing anything at the back end. The worker roles are doing some things though.

Comment: Also, I have only one web role and it still is showing two browser windows. i.e., only one option for Open Browser for HTTP End Point. Still showing two browser windows is strange. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the last Azure SDK edition v1.4. With the previous versions of the SDK there were some performance problems when running a service locally. Regarding the two opened windows problem, this might happen because the compute and the storage emulator were started manually on the local machine and not by the Visual Studio. At least in my case this was the problem. After shutting down the app., the compute and the storage emulator and running again the app.(F5) everything should be fine.

Comment: I have updated the Azure SDK, but still same problem or infact problems. Two windows open and the website often gets so slow that it says Web page Unavailable message...

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen with Chrome and Firefox. It doesn't happen with IE. Sorry I can't explain "why."